# Join a table two times on different fields

Tags: mysql, outer-join

```
topics: title, poster_id (int), last_poster(int), date
players: id, name

SELECT *, f.name AS forum 
FROM topics t 
LEFT JOIN forums f ON f.id = t.forum_id 
LEFT JOIN players p ON p.id = t.poster_id
```

In topics I have two fields with the ID of the author of the topic (poster_id), and a field with the ID of the player that posted the most recent message in that topic (last_poster).

And then I get the name of the author based on that ID in the players table.

Could I somehow also get the name of the last_poster?

Adding `AND p.id = t.last_poster` dont give any error but how am I supposed to print it? as `<?php echo $row['name'] ;?>` will print the author of the topic.

Comment: Why select f.name twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join with the players table twice: once for each column.
You need to use Aliases for the players table, as well as different output names for the columns (otherwise $row['name'] gets confusing).

```
SELECT t.*, f.name AS forum, p.name as poster_name, lp.name as lastposter_name
FROM topics t 
LEFT JOIN forums f ON f.id = t.forum_id 
LEFT JOIN players p ON p.id = t.poster_id
LEFT JOIN players lp ON lp.id = t.last_poster
```

From php, you can refer to these columns with their aliases

```
$creator = $row['poster_name'];
$lastposter = $row['lastposter_name'];
```